# Why does pycharm have this situation?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

Obviously, the same program is run, and the code is the same. Why do two of them appear the same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Please keep in mind that this site is not tech support. It appears that this question is purely about Pycharm itself as a program, and not anything to do with *writing the code*. Regardless, we can't really tell you why a program does something under certain conditions, unless we actually know what those conditions are. If that's a listing of source code files, then the most obvious explanation is that you actually have a separate `1week cat.py` and `1week cat (1).py` on your computer.

Comment: What is the problem?? If it is why the same file appears twice, you may have saved it twice.

Comment: Windows typically handles duplicate filenames by adding `(1)` to the end of the second file.  You saved the same filename twice.

Comment: (By the way, it is a good idea to make sure your file names for Python source code, are restricted to things that could be used as variable names - so, no spaces, start with a letter, etc. Otherwise you will not be able to use the normal mechanism to `import` that file.)

Comment: This can happen inside pycharm or other editors. If you copy / paste to a new window and say "save", programs like pycharm may come up with a default value of an existing name plus " (1)" to make it unique. Pressing "save as" can do the same thing. You should open each of the files and see if they are exactly the same. If so, delete the " (1)" version to avoid confusion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - that's a good point about module names. But just to be clear, top level scripts that you run but don't import do not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute scripts with the same name but different file locations or run configurations this can happen.

It can be useful in a variety of situations; where you want to run the same script in multiple different versions of python.  Each Run configuration can be setup to use a separate interpreter.  Though, it would be wise to rename the run configuration.

In this case, pycharm simply took the name of the script and appended `(1)` when it saw another run configuration of that same name already existed.